# Deleting an array of complex types

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, destructor, delete-operator

If I have a complex class A, and I define an array that contains this class(or pointers to objects from this class), if I use delete[], does it free the content of each element of the array then the array itself, or do i have to manually free all elements(delete arr[i]) and then call delete[]?

** I'm not allowed to use the STL

Comment: please show your code. `delete arr[i]` would only work when the array elements are pointers, in which case `delete[]` will not care about the objects pointed to by those pointers

Comment: [Pro Tip] Don't use `new`.  Use a `std::vector<T>` instead.  It will clean up everything for you assuming your `T` has a destructor that functions correctly.

Comment: Try to use rule of 0 (3/5/0) and use vector, and don't manually handle resource.

Comment: Whether the array "contains this class" or "pointers to objects from this class" is not a trivial, insignificant, detail. It is very important factor to consider, for this question. Therefore, no single answer is possible, for the entire question.

Comment: If you have `A arr[10];` you do not use `delete[] arr;` at all.  You only `delete` what you `new`.  You only `delete[]` what you `new[]`.  And in modern C++, you ought to consider containers and smart pointers instead.

Answer (score 1):

> if I use delete[], does it

If you allocate a dynamic array using `new`, then passing pointer to first element of that array into `delete[]` will invoke the destructor of each element, and deallocate the memory. If you didn't allocate a dynamic array, then using `delete[]` will result in undefined behaviour.

> do i have to manually free all elements(delete arr[i])

Depends on what the array contains. If the array elements are owning bare pointers to dynamically allocated non-array objects, then yes. If the array doesn't contain that, then using `delete` will result in undefined behaviour or an ill-formed program.

P.S. Don't use `new` and `delete[]`. Use `std::vector` instead if you need a dynamic array.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, I'm not allowed to use the STL in my code that's why im using a normal array, so if I create an array of pointers using new should I do a loop and delete arr[i] and after the loop delete[] arr, or delete[] arr  alone is suffecient?

Comment: @AdanSuleiman Depends on what the pointers in the array point to.

Comment: they point to a class that contains two pointers to AVL trees

Answer (score 0):

Just delete[] array is sufficient. It is guaranteed that each element of the array is deleted when you delete an array using delete[] operator.

Comment: This is not a sufficient answer without knowing the details of OPs code. OP states that _I define an array that contains this class(or pointers to objects from this class)_. Thus there is a difference that OP has to be aware of: Instances in the array would be deleted by `delete[]` but if it were pointers to objects created by `new` these had to be deleted individually.